# Modeling Name-Date-Period composite key in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm somewhat confused as to what the proper secondary index would look like for DynamoDB.

I have Name, Date, Period, Data attributes and want an index that lets me efficiently lookup by Name, Date, and Period.

I also want to efficiently lookup all Names for a given Date.

I tried setting my secondary index partition key to Name since I want those to be grouped together on nodes.  And added attribute projections for Date and Period.  Is this the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Every single access pattern needs to be enumerated and you need to think about its corresponding retrieval mechanism. Your base table provides one access mechanism. You can use GSIs for the additional mechanisms.

The base table and each GSI provide a PK and SK for you to use. The PK must be an individual value (sometimes composed of several values concatenated together with a separator like hash). The SK can be a sortable value, used either as a value or range. Those are the tools at your disposal.

"All names for a given date" might use a GSI where the date is the PK and the names are the SK.

At reasonable scale you don't have to think too much about hot partitions. At high scale (more than 1,000 write units needed per second) you'll have to think harder before putting everything under a single date PK for the GSI.